# th:field in jquery and bind with thymeleaf field

Tags: jquery, html, thymeleaf

I want to add new row without going to server side.And I want to access testDtoList in my controller when form is submitted.But testDtoList contains first initialized row only.The new added row is not binded to testDtoList.How do I add th:field in jquery?

```
<table id="testList" class="table table-bordered "> 
    <thead>
        <tr class="success">
            <th class="text-center">No.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                        
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="testDto, iterStat : *{testDtoList}">     
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{testDtoList[__${iterStat.index}__].data}" /></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
<button type="button" name="add" id = "addnewrow">add</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit">submitToController</button>

$(function() {
    $("#addnewrow").click(function () {
        $("#testList").each(function () {
            var row = "<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>";
            $('tbody', this).append(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is $("#testList")?

Comment: you have some errors in your jquery code.check in console. (FireBug)

Comment: Thanks for your advice.@DaveyDaveDave .But I don't want to go to server side just for adding row.I want to add rows as much as i want and go to server side only when "submit" button is clicked. Anyway,thanks for your interest.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that's what I thought that section of the docs was talking about when I saw it the other day, but should have read it properly before posting! I'll remove that comment to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give your `input` the correct `name`. You'll notice your first initialised row is named such as `name="testDtoList[0].data"`, so your newly added row should have `name="testDtoList[1].data"` and so on.

Something like the below should work:

```
var newIndex = $("#testList > tbody > tr").length;
var name = "testDtoList[" + newIndex + "].data"
var row = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="' + name + '"></input></td></tr>';
$('tbody', this).append(row);
```